# Installing modules seems to work when running python in terminal but not when running a script

Tags: python, terminal

Hi so I downloaded the source code for beautifulsoup4. I moved it to a folder .../Desktop/Python_modules/ which is where I like to keep all the folders for the modules I down load and tried to install it as follows:

1. went to the directory
2. ran:

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

How comes now when I open python in terminal i can import beautifulsoup4 using "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" but when i have it in a script which is executed using ./script it gives the following error: 'ImportError: No module named requests'?

And How would I go about installing beautifulsoup4 so that i can run the script using "./"?

Just for completion: I'm using a mac

Comment: That depends on where the module `requests` is installed and if that location is part of `sys.path` when trying to execute the import. You can put something like this `import sys; print(sys.path)` inside your script to see if it is looking for the requests module in the right place. Read the relevant [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for an explanation of how imports work.

Comment: Note that this error is caused by python failing to find a module called `requests`. This might be a requirement that `bs4` needs, or you are importing `requests` in addition to BeautifulSoup in your script.

Comment: Have you installed Python from homebrew or some other third party source?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing suggests strongly that there are two different versions of Python installed on your system.  If your scripts start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then running `./script` will always run `/usr/bin/python`.  If you have another Python installed (say, via homebrew, which will give you `/usr/local/bin/python`) then running `python` in the terminal will probably get you *that* version.

So...running `python setup.py install` will install the module where it is visible to `/usr/local/bin/python` but not to `/usr/bin/python`, which is why it works for you when you run `python` in the terminal but not when you run a script.

You can fix this by running your scripts like this:

```
python script
```

Or by modifying the scripts to start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Which will look for a `python` binary in your `$PATH` rather than using a fixed path.

(Or you can install modules by running `/usr/bin/python setup.py install`)